# Error while create barcode in vb.net Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, barcode

I'm a beginner learning vb.net. I tried to create barcodes using barcodeLib but I'm getting an error which is System.Exception: 'EUPCA-1: Data length invalid. (Length must be 11 or 12). Can somebody help my understand where did I go wrong.

here is my code:

```
Dim barcode As Barcode = New Barcode()
    Dim forecolor As Color = Color.Black
    Dim backcolor As Color = Color.Transparent
    Dim image As Image = barcode.Encode(TYPE.UPCA, txtBarcode.Text, forecolor, backcolor, CInt(picBarcode.Width * 0.8), CInt(picBarcode.Height * 0.8))
    picBarcode.Image = image
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that the txtBarcode.Text isn't 11 or 12 characters in length? Just checked the spec for a UPC barcode, it should be 12 digits.

Comment: Check the official GS1 docs for barcode requirements https://gs1go2.azureedge.net/cdn/ff/mTugzXOdBT2AunS2AYC-a_Raz8C3fhmB0Urhkl_9D9M/1627291955/public/2021-07/gs1_general_specifications.pdf  Think you want to look around page 256 of that doc

Comment: @Hursey Not sure reading into a 500 page barcode spec is really an answer on how to generate a barcode using an off the shelf package. If you were writing a package to generate a barcode then it might be useful,.

Comment: @Slugsie Did point to the actual page with the requirements for a UPC bar code.  It has the requirements there so it us to the developer to ensure they provide the validation to ensure correct and complaint information is used.  Is it the answer, probably not but I would expect most developers to do the appropriate research on standards, before implementing standards

Comment: @Hursey Like I said I would agree if the OP was writing a component to generate a barcode. They aren't, they're using a pre-written barcode generator, one that generated an error that should have been enough to point the OP to what the issue was without having to refer to the published standard for a UPC barcode. BTW, you pointed to page 256, whereas the info was actually on page 265.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [example](https://github.com/barnhill/barcodelib#example) shows, length of 'txtBarcode.Text' must be 11 or 12 characters and numeric data only. Like '038000356216' or '03800035621'

Comment: thanks for your help. Indeed it only accepts 11 characters and not 12 or less. It works fine. Sorry it does say not to thank or write comments here but I didn't find options to reply you. Thanking you here.